# Is there a way to open links in the browser via a website (in mobile apps)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, web

When a website is loaded via an app in either android or ios is there a way to force those links to open in the default browser of the device?

I have tried with the basic `_blank` html attribute on the links but no luck. I also tried this code but still the same - the website opens as part of the app...

```
$('.lnkAtoZApp').click(function (e) {        
    window.open(this.href, '_system'); this.href = "javascript:void(0)"; event.preventDefault();            
});
```

Comment: Are you using cordova in app browser plugin? Because as per docs, the _system opens the url in system's web browser - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: you min open in chrome browser ?

Comment: no its a normal website which is accessed by an app... We want those links in the website to open in the devices main browser

Comment: @iioannou Hello, Have you found a way?